# Flex not working properly in Android Web View 1 on Tablet

Tags: android, css, webview, flexbox

I am displaying 20 photos inside a DIV and use flex-wrap: wrap to make the photos wrap when the window is made smaller. When I look at the page from a tablet, Google Chrome displays it well, however, Android Web View 1 browser doesn't display this properly. Can someone please let me know how I can edit the code so that it will display the images properly in Web View 1.

Please see below: In the 1st screen shot below, you can see that all the photos wrap correctly and all are displayed within the screen when viewed from a Chrome browser:

[image]

In the 2nd Screen Shot, I'm viewing the same page using Android Web View 1: See how the photos are not wrapped and they go out of the screen:

[image]

The link to site is here. The CSS is also embeded withihn the HTML so you just have to right click and select View Source to see the code :  http://www.geocities.ws/sonnyk2015/sitelayout/index.html

Comment: Have you checked for browser compatibility? http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @Michael_B: I just removed flex from my code and instead used float and the problem is gone. Now it works on all browsers, PCs or Tablets or Phones....